# How can I add data labels in my stack plot using matplotlib.pylot.stackplot()?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I am currently learning how to create different plots in MatPlotLib. So far, I can create a basic stackplot but i wonder if i can add labels on my data values.

Below is my code:

```
    `An example that shows each employees contribution to a project over several days.`
    plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

    days_x = list(range(1, 10))

    emp1 = [8,6,5,5,4,2,1,1,0]
    emp2 = [0,1,2,2,2,4,4,4,4]
    emp3 = [0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]

    emp_labels = ['Employee 1', 'Employee 2', 'Employee 3']

    plt.stackplot(minutes, emp1, emp2, emp3, labels=emp_labels)

    `Labels`
    `title`
    plt.title('Contributed Hours of Work in 8-hour Shifts', fontdict={'fontsize' : 18})
    `x - axis`
    plt.xticks(np.arange(1, 10, 1))
    plt.xlabel('Days')
    `y - axis`
    plt.ylabel('Hours')
    plt.set
    plt.yticks(np.arange(1, 10, 1))

    plt.legend(loc=1)

    `fitting`
    plt.tight_layout()
```

Here is the output: [image: output]

I wonder if I can add the values of the three employee lists on the stack plot.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code, such as missing "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt" at the beginning, non-Python style comments, etc. Anyway, it looks like you want to see the values of contributed hours of work directly on your stack plot. You can do it by drawing a vertical line across each day with [matplotlib.pyplot.vlines](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.vlines.html#matplotlib.pyplot.vlines) and by putting the respective text labels with [matplotlib.pyplot.annotate](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate) close to different sections of such a line:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# An example that shows each employees contribution to a project over several days
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

days_x = list(range(1, 10))

emp1 = [8,6,5,5,4,2,1,1,0]
emp2 = [0,1,2,2,2,4,4,4,4]
emp3 = [0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]

emp_labels = ['Employee 1', 'Employee 2', 'Employee 3']

plt.stackplot(days_x, emp1, emp2, emp3, labels=emp_labels)

# plot dotted vertical lines for all days, going from min to max number of working hours
min_y = min(emp1 + emp2 + emp3)
max_y = max(emp1 + emp2 + emp3)
plt.vlines(days_x, min_y, max_y, color='k', ls=':')

# put non-zero numbers of working hours of all employees slightly to the right of each vertical line, in the middle of employee-related parts of the data
h_offset = 0.1
for e1, e2, e3, d in zip(emp1, emp2, emp3, days_x):
    if e1 != 0:
        plt.annotate(e1, (d + h_offset, e1/2))  # assuming that the first employee data is at the bottom
    if e2 != 0:
        plt.annotate(e2, (d + h_offset, e1 + e2/2))  # assuming that the second employee data is above the first employee data
    if e3 != 0:
        plt.annotate(e3, (d + h_offset, e1 + e2 + e3/2)) # assuming that the third employee data is above the second employee data

# plot title
plt.title('Contributed Hours of Work in 8-hour Shifts', fontdict={'fontsize' : 18})

# axes labels
plt.xlabel('Days')
plt.ylabel('Hours')

# legend
plt.legend()

# fitting
plt.tight_layout()

# showing
plt.show()
```

I guess the plot looks better if the axes ticks are generated automatically, because in this case you don't have that strange "9" in the top left corner, which doesn't correspond to any value of working hours. Voilà:
[image]